# Importing JSON-ified HTTP Response Headers Through a .txt File into a Mongo Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, mongodb, header

The format of a JSON-ified HTTP response header is below:

```
{
  "url": "aalfs.com",
  "statusCode": 301,
  "headers": {
    "date": "Tue, 12 Mar 2013 19:36:28 GMT",
    "server": "Strategi HTTPD V2R5M1",
    "connection": "Keep-Alive",
    "content-length": "0",
    "location": "/index.htm"
  }
}
```

Using MongoJS, I have programmed Mongo to interpret the data as such, with three main variables - `url`, `statusCode`, `headers`:

```
function site(url, statusCode, headers){
    this.url = url;
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.headers = headers;
}
```

With `url` as the `__id`:

```
db.scrape.ensureIndex({url:1},{unique:true});
```

In my code, I can import HTTP response headers into my database via this object:

```
var site1 = new site("www.thing.com", "300", {"header information"});

db.scrape.save(site1, function(err, savedUser){
    if(err||!savedUser) console.log("URL " + site.url + " not saved because of error " + err);
    else console.log("URL " + savedUser.url +" saved");
});
```

My question is - I am looking for a more convenient/efficient way to important hundreds of HTTP response headers into my Mongo database. I have hundreds of those JSON-ified HTTP response headers in the format that is demonstrated above, saved in a .txt file. Is it possible for Mongo to simply read my .txt file and interpret and import into Mongo?

Comment: if you have json files import them from terminal, why use node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongoimport. Look at the various options [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoimport/)

You will have to replace 'url' literal with '_id'